# ¿Cómo ejecutar correctamente un POST en C#?

Tags: c#, post

Estoy realizando mi primer consumo de servicios por medio de C#, pero tengo inconvenientes al querer realizar la petición POST.

Cuando se ejecuta el método **PostAsJsonAsync** el valor retornado es null, en vez de cargar los datos en el servicio. Ocasionando que al momento de ingresar al **IF** que evalúa si el response fue cargado correctamente me devuelva el mensaje error. No se genera ninguna excepción en el proceso.

¿Me podrían indicar que fallo estoy cometiendo? o ¿Cómo se debe realizar correctamente POST en C#?

Este es el código con el que me encuentro trabajando.

```
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var response2= new Registro(){ nombre = "Alex", email = "prueba@gmail.com",
        password = "1234567",
        password_confirmation = "1234567"
    };
    var respuesta= await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(url2, response2);
    if (respuesta.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        Console.WriteLine("Info cargada");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Error");


    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Mientras la clase de las propiedades es:

```
public class Registro
{
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string password_confirmation { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y revisaste que error te devuelve?

Comment: ¿No obtienes ninguna excepción?

Comment: @Mateo no, como tal no me devuelve ningún tipo de excepción.  Evalúa correctamente el if y como la respuesta no se sube, me devuelve el mensaje de error que coloque.

Comment: @gbianchi gracias, lo revisare nuevamente para formularla se mejor manera. Respecto al error, no me devuelve excepciones, ya que el mensaje de "error" es el que yo mismo coloque que muestre cuando evalúa si fue exitoso o no la subida de la informacion

Comment: y no deberia devolverte ninguna, porque la llamada fue exitosa, pero la otra parte devolvio que tuvo un problema con tu llamada.. vuelvo a preguntar, revisaste que fue devuelto? porque por mas que la llamada no haya sido correcta, devuelve el codigo de error y el motivo...

Comment: @gbianchi según lo que revise lo que me devuelve **respuesta**  es un false respecto a SuccesStatusCode y en su StatusCode me inidca **UnprocessableEntity**.

Comment: Y buscate ese error en internet? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/422

Comment: @gbianchi de hecho no había buscado que significaba el error. Pero ahora que lo veo me causa mayor duda. Antes de empezar a consumir estos servicios en C# los comprobé en insomnia y me funcionan correctamente, mantengo la misma sintaxis con la que envío el json.

Comment: Entonces no se como podemos ayudarte. Todo tu codigo es correcto por lo que se ve. No sabemos que hace esa API (y ojo, porque es un test, tal vez a la gente que te lo esta tomando mucho no le guste que lo hagas publico). Como esta, es dificil ayudarte..

Comment: @gbianchi agradezco mucho tu apoyo y ayudarme a entender que realmente el código esta correcto. Tienes toda la razón no había meditado en no colocar la API directamente (ya lo corregí para solo mostrar el código).

Comment: ¿@AlexZacarias tu API no requiere token en la cabecera? ¿Donde lo estableces? Raro porque ahorita que tenías la url de la api hice un GET y me divolvió  _"Nil JSON web token"_  por lo que estoy casi seguro necesitas un token.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez si la API genera un token cuando haces el POST del registro, (o al menos lo hacia la primera vez que lo probé en Insomnia), pero no se como se manejan estos Token o las cabeceras

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realmente la forma de hacer la petición depende exclusivamente de la API, y cómo esté programada para recibir una petición.

He probado tu código y literalmente funciona. Por favor, imprime como tal el **TEXTO** de la respuesta, no el código del error. Probablemente lo que estés obteniendo es un simple error de validación porque el usuario ya existe.

He probado tu código y de manera literal te devuelve el usuario creado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando lo vuelves a ejecutar te da de hecho mensajes significativos, como que el email ya fue tomado antes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tu código:

```
using System.Net.Http.Json;

var url = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var registro = new Registro()
    {
        nombre = "Jaime", 
        email = "jaime1234@gmail.com",
        password = "1234567",
        password_confirmation = "1234567"
    };
    
    var respuesta = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(url, registro);
    Console.WriteLine(await respuesta.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
}
```

Comment: entonces ¿la razón por la cual siempre el If me devolvía un error era por la validación?, ya lo  probé  justo como me indicas y funciona correctamente. Te agradezco mucho por tu ayuda.